# put together a function pointer and a object

Tags: c++

I try to give a reference to a member function (func) to a function (Multiprotocol) and call it with an object (z) of this class.
But i have problems with the line

```
result = z.*f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

I tried things like

```
z.(*f) (std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

and

```
z.(*(&f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

But i don't knwow how to this. Can anybody help me?

```
class test
{ 
   public:
        static int func()
        {
            std::cout << "in func";
        }
 };


class MultiProtocol
{
   public:

      template<typename Function, typename... Args>
      bool functionImpl(Function f, Args&&... args)
      {
         int result = 0;
         result = z.*f(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
         return result;
      }

      private:
      test z;
};
```

Main is:

```
int main()
{
MultiProtocol rr;
rr.functionImpl(&test::func);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly, it is:

```
(z.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

Cannot be

- `z.(*f) (std::forward<Args>(args)...))`
- `z.(*(&f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...));`

as we should use operator `.*` (or `->*`).

`z.*f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` would be valid if `f(args...)` would return `int test::*` (pointer on member) as it is actually `z .* (f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))`.